# Cosmos DB SQL ORDER BY clause using a result base expressions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I can successfully run the following Cosmos DB SQL query

```
SELECT d.P1
FROM d in c.P2
```

getting the results

```
[
    {
        "P1": {
            ...
            "EID": 35009
        }
    },
    {
        "P1": {
            ...
            "EID": 14001
        }
    },
...
```

Now I want to order my results so I try

```
SELECT d.P1
FROM d in c.P2
ORDER BY d.P1.EID DESC
```

But I get an error

```
Failed to query item for container <my_container>:
 Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":7,"end":8},"code":"SC2001","message":"Identifier 'c' could not be resolved."}]}
```

**How can I get my results sorted by an expression based on the result itself?**

Comment: No idea why your first query even works but my guess is the query engine is ignoring your use of IN within your first query.  The use of IN is to iterate over an array. But I see no arrays with a property name of c. Here is a doc that shows the correct usage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-object-array#Iteration

Comment: @MarkBrown filtering works (as per the document you indicated), but sorting does not.